# Asp net cannot accept json with brackets [ ]

Tags: c#, json

Here is my method how i create a register into Asp net

```
 public class RegisterBindingModel
    {

        public string Email { get; set; }
        public string Password { get; set; }
        public string ConfirmPassword { get; set; }
    }
    async void Register(string email,string password, string confirmPassword)
    {
        List<RegisterBindingModel> mItems = new List<RegisterBindingModel>();
        mItems.Add(new RegisterBindingModel { Email = email, Password = password, ConfirmPassword = confirmPassword });

        var json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(mItems);
        using (var client = new HttpClient())
        {
            client.Timeout = TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(20000);
            var response = await client.PostAsync("http://localhost:49826/api/Account/Register", new StringContent(json, Encoding.UTF8, "application/json"));

            if (response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
            {
                string content = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
                Console.Write((int)response.StatusCode);

            }
            else
            {
                string content = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
                Console.Write((int)response.StatusCode);

            }
        }

    }
    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Register("dimitris2@in.gr", "Password1?", "Password1?");
    }
```

I am getting error 400 Invalid request Cannot deserialize the current json array eg 1,2,3... If i will remove first and last bracket from string , then it works. But it is not standar json format. How can fix this?

This is how my string looks like:

`[{"Email":"dimitris2@in.gr","Password":"Password1?","ConfirmPassword":"Password1?"}]`

Comment: Well, you are serializing a List, which the `[ ]` brackets represent. It looks like you want to just serialize the item directly, however.

Comment: I update my question

Comment: Remove the list and serialize the object directly.  Why are you adding a model to a list before serializing it if the endpoint doesn't expect a list of entities?

Answer (score 4):

It looks like you are passing a single-element array to the server, while the server expects a single element coming by itself. This can be addressed by serializing the object without adding it to the list:

```
var json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(new RegisterBindingModel {
    Email = email,
    Password = password,
    ConfirmPassword = confirmPassword
});
```

Comment: Your answer works, but is there any way to send query using list collection?

Comment: @Dim if the server wont accept a collection there is not much else you can do. Send the single item.

Comment: @Dim It is up to the service to take or to reject the request in a specific format. If you modify the service running at `http://localhost:49826/api/Account/Register` to accept arrays, passing JSON arrays would work. Currently, though, it looks like the service is programmed to reject JSON arrays.

Comment: What if i want to send multiple elements (multiple emails)? should i send them directly? without using list?

Comment: @Dim From what I can tell, it looks like you need to send them one-by-one in a loop.